# Shnayim mikra ve'echad targum in English

Tags: halacha, translation, english, shnayim-mikra

Can I fulfill the obligation of shnayim mikra by saying the pasuk two times and then the English translation one time?

Comment: How good of a translation is it? Artscroll might work but I doubt JPS does.

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm not sure I agree with the edit: true, it should be clarified that the translation is being used as the targum in 'shnaim mikra veechad targum', but it isn't agreed upon that the proper/required manner of doing so is pasuk by pasuk

Comment: I don't know enough to write an actual answer, but I believe that most agree that Rashi is a good substitute for Onkelos, so if you go the Chabad Daily Study website, read the Hebrew twice and the English once, and read Rashi's commentary (which is also available in English on the website), then that's a way to fulfill the mitzvah. The problem I see with the English alone is that Onkelos was an interpretative rather than a literal translation, so it is like reading a commentary as well as a translation.

Comment: @DoubleAA, Artscroll is not that accurate a translation as NJPS and likely on par with OJPS for accuracy. Personally I use Koren due to the scholarly nature thereof.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt That's my point. The less accurate the better.

Comment: @Kordovero That's why I said Artscroll might work even if JPS doesn't.

Comment: I have heard in the name of Rav Avigdor Nebenzahl that one can at least be yotzei targum with Rav Aryeh Kaplans english translation "The Living Torah"

Comment: http://www.koltorah.org/ravj/shnayimmikra.htm

Answer (score 2):

SA OC 285:1 States the requirement is 2 times mikra and 1 time Targum. It is clear from the commentaries that Targum means Targum Unkilus. 285:2 allows Rashi, stating the both are done by one who fears Heaven.  MB 5 (and Be'er Heiteiv 3) quote the Taz, recomending a good explanatory text such as Tzeiena Ur'ena, to be used in place of Rashi, if the person is not holding by understanding Rashi.

So, for a translation of the p'sukim to fulfill the obligation, it must incorporate an explanation.

Comment: And for any names that are not translated one must either read the hebrew a third time or possibly the the transliteration.

Comment: Why can't it be Targum Yonason? Or Neofiti? (And, yes, I know someone who did this after getting tired of Onkelos.)

Comment: Did the mechaber even have access to those?

Comment: @BoruchTkatch It's not unreasonable that he did, but even if not why should that matter?

Comment: The meforshim say he meant Targum Unkilus. Whether Targum Yonoson and the others are (just as) acceptable, is not the question. Since we want to know what he meant, knowing what he had available is likely to matter.