# Can I do shnayim mikrah v'echad targum in English?

Tags: halacha

Can one fulfill his obligation of "shnayim mikrah v'echad targum" with an English translation of the Torah in place of the Targum? For example, Rav Aryeh Kaplan's The Living Torah or the English translation of Rav S.R. Hirsch's translation.

Comment: See particularly [this comment](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43329/shnayim-mikra-veechad-targum-in-english?rq=1#comment112355_43329) which mentions R' Aryeh Kaplan's The Living Torah specifically, claiming that Rav Avigdor Nebenzahl says it is a valid targum for this purpose.

Comment: VTC as being duplicate (@Rish's) comment. Viewing the answer in that question, though, I would agree that the problem with many English translations is that they miss the mark. Rash"i is a commentary, not a translation, though sometimes, he does literally, translate. My Aramaic is not great. Can another MY member who knows Aramic well comment on how accurate Onkelos is in terms of literal translation? Would you consider it the best available?