# Steinsaltz Chumash for targum of shnayim mikra

Tags: halacha, pentateuch-chumash, shnayim-mikra

The Steinsaltz Chumash's English translation has commentary and explanation placed between the words of the pesukim. This added text can take the form of its own clause or sentences, or it can continue the original text, as is done in the Steinsaltz Talmud.

At the start of a parashah and at changes of topic or scene, there are added paragraphs of text that provide an overview and insight.

For these reasons, it seems that one may be able to count reading the translation in this chumash as the targum in shnayim mikra v'echad targum. Would this be a halachically sound option?

Comment: possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43329/759

Comment: If i remember correctly Rabbi Chaim Pinchas Scheinberg obm was so impressed by Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan's Living Torah translation that he said one could be yotzei in shnayim mikra v'echad targum if one could not understand aramaic but idk how accurate the claim is firstly and secondly if he truly meant it (or if it was just a way to praise the translation). In either case he did not say the same for Steinsaltz although maybe this leaves room for suggesting one could be yotzei from it?

Comment: @ezra the Steinsaltz translation didn’t exist when RCPS lived